# Filling in lines on scanned line art GIMP

Tags: gimp

Is there an easier way to fill in the lines in a scanned drawing. Easier than just tracing the whole thing with the brush tool. I scanned in my drawing and then used threshold to get rid of the paper background, but the lines are incomplete and pixelated with white. A little help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not a pro and am doing this for a safety eduactors group. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Have you tried tracing?

Comment: I tried tracing with the brush tool but I'm not great at it with my mouse.  as think that there was a way to make the lines sharper with some type of blur or other filter, but I'm not educated enough to know which ones to use or how.

Comment: Is this meant to be printed on offset? Where will this graphic be used, what kind of document?

Answer (score 1):

You can fill-in the holes in the outline by doing:

- Select-by-Color (click on black outline)
- Select > Grow (1px)
- Select > Shrink (1px)
- Bucket-Fill (whole selection) with black

Unfortunately, in this particular case, this will still leave a rather jagged outline because your earlier thresholding to remove the background has also removed all the anti-aliasing. So to produce a smooth outline, convert the selection to a path and back again before bucket-filling, thus:

- (first three steps as above)
- Select > To Path
- (right-click in the Paths dialog) Path to Selection
- create a new layer (white)
- Bucket-Fill (whole selection) with black